# Difference between MS-debug and MASM assembler

Tags: assembly

I just doing continuously a research for language assembly through numerous sources regarding on structures, cpu flags, registers and many more.

However what are the differences on learning debug and masm assembler? Since codes are different at all.

Which is better for a fresh start?

Since our school have this curriculum and seems using debug built in for Windows.

P.S: I'm dealing on 8086 Chip information language assembly

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. You seem to be asking about the difference between apples and figs.

Comment: I mean what are the difference of built-in debug on Windows and MASM assembler for low level language in terms like coding?

Comment: Do you _code_ with the debugger?

Comment: Quite a bit as I don't have yet an idea which will be used for our subject language assembly. Primarily testing debug but why codes syntax are different from masm tutorial.

Comment: Because they are not the same thing and do not have the same purpose.

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember debug is just assembly, not a macro assembler, etc, so it is a bit more raw/pure.  Masm, and others have assembler directives you can throw in to make programming easier (if you are into that sort of thing).  Nasm is something you didnt mention but possibly a good start.

At least back in the day, debug was always there so you didnt have to go find tools you could just start programming.

masm/nasm is going to make life a bit easier, but all should work just fine as far as generating machine code from assembly language

Answer (score 2):

`debug.com` is a **debugger**, intended for debugging existing programs. While it does have an "assemble" command, it's not intended for serious development. You can't use symbolic labels or data declarations. You can't even save the entered assembler text to a file. If you are only making toy programs with a dozen instructions or so, then sure, you can use `debug.com` and hope you don't make any typos. But for something more substantial it's better to use a full assembler, either MASM or any of the alternatives (TASM, NASM, FASM, YASM, JWASM etc.).